# Group MySQL rows into buckets based on Min value

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table with shopping options which looks like

| Product | Seller | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ProductA | Seller1 | 10.0 |
| ProductA | Seller2 | 10.2 |
| ProductA | Seller3 | 12 |
| ProductA | Seller4 | 13.6 |
| ProductB | Seller5 | 5.0 |
| ProductB | Seller6 | 5.1 |
| ProductB | Seller7 | 5.2 |
| ProductB | Seller8 | 5.7 |
| ProductB | Seller9 | 5.8 |

I'd like to group shopping options into buckets based on the minimun product price, and divide all options into 2 groups:

GroupA: minimum price to (minimum price) * 10 % - competitive/fair prices

GroupB: above (minimum price) * 10 % - expensive prices

and count the number of sellers in each group

So the results should look like

| Product | Min Price | Price threshold | GroupA sellers count | GroupB sellers count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ProductA | 10.0 | 11.0 | 2 | 2 |
| ProductB | 5.0 | 5.5 | 3 | 2 |

Is there a way to do it using MySQL capabilities only?

Comment: *Is there a way to do it using MySQL capabilities only?* Of course. use subquery which calculates `Price threshold`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT t1.Product, 
       t3.Treshold, 
       SUM(t1.Price <= t3.Treshold) GroupA, 
       SUM(t1.Price > t3.Treshold) GroupB
FROM test t1
JOIN ( SELECT Product, MIN(Price) * 1.1 Treshold
       FROM test t2
       GROUP BY 1 ) t3 USING (Product)
GROUP BY 1
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=be61a9a526477ae821fa38c9cb450e8d

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT Product, MIN(Price) as min_price, ...
FROM table
GROUP BY Product
```

It is not clear how you are computing price threshold, but this is very simple to add a column for to compute.